# Rails 3 - Nested Forms, how to count nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, count, nested-forms

Hi, I'm a Rails newbie and this is my first *stackoverflow* question.

I'm currently writing a **poll application**, the concept is very simple.
The User can create a `new poll` by giving it a title and some possible answers.

The answers can be added or removed by using javascript:void(0) links (see picture)

Everything works great so far (thanks to ryanb's nested_form [gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)), but now I'm asking myself how can I **count the number of the given answers**, so I can limit it to say at most 5 answers per question? 
(currently you can create an unlimited number of answers)
The answer creating part of the poll form looks like - [THIS](http://i52.tinypic.com/1178thd.png) - in the browser.


Poll-Model (**poll.rb**):

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers,  :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Answer-Model (**answer.rb**):

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :poll
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

My current approach of counting the answers (**polls_controller.rb**):

```
def new
  @poll = Poll.new
  2.times { @poll.answers.build }
end


def create  
  ...

  if @poll.answers.count > 10
    flash[:alert] = 'Too many answers (not exceeding 10), please remove some'
    render :action => 'new'
    return
  end

  if @poll.save
    redirect_to poll_path(category_slug(@poll), @poll.id), :notice => 'Successfully created poll.'
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end

  ...
end
```

Obviously my method won't work, because the answers **aren't created yet**, so my question is:

- How and where (*JavaScript*, *Polls-Controller*, *Poll-Model*) should I count the number of the given answers, so I can limit the number

Thanks, I really appreciate every answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does :limit as part of nested_attributes work?

e.g.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :limit => 5, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for. Now I'm getting a ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::TooManyRecords exception. Do you know how can I redirect back to the new poll action (probably with a custom flash message)?